# Why counter is not increasing

Tags: javascript, html

please help me solve this code guys I am stuck here I am new to JavaScript that's why I can't solve this simple error

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>

            <script>
                var scr1 = 0;
    var scr2 = 0;
    var counter = 0;

    window.onload = function () {
    var YS = document.getElementById("YS");
    var CS = document.getElementById("CS");
    var mid = document.getElementById("mid");

    YS.innerHTML = "Your Score :  " + scr1 + counter  ;
    CS.innerHTML = "Com Score  :  " + scr2 ;

     }


    function srt() {
         counter++;
    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2 class="scr1" id="YS">Your Score :</h1>
        <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
        <center>
        <div class="mid" id="mid"><p>0</p></p></div>
        <div class="srt" id="none" onclick="srt()">
            <h4>Start</h4>
        </div>
        </center>

        </body>
    </html>
```

> I hope you understand my question please help me if you can

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: You are not doing anything with counter to display it. It is increasing

Comment: Any code for help

Comment: You just need to do something with it, that is up to you and whatever you have it there in the first place is for, how is anyone supposed to provide you code for that?

Answer (score 1):

Your counter is increasing, but you didn't show the change when it's increasing.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script>
        var scr1 = 0;
        var scr2 = 0;
        var counter = 0;

        window.onload = function () {
            var YS = document.getElementById("YS");
            var CS = document.getElementById("CS");
            var mid = document.getElementById("mid");

        }


        function srt() {
            console.log(counter);
            counter++;

            YS.innerHTML = "Your Score :  " + scr1 + counter  ;
            CS.innerHTML = "Com Score  :  " + scr2 ;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 class="scr1" id="YS">Your Score :</h1>
    <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
    <div class="mid" id="mid"><p>0</p></p></div>
    <div class="srt" id="none" >
        <button onclick="srt()">Start</button>
    </div>
    </center>

    </body>
</html>
```

next time, use **console.log()** to do debugging

Answer (score 0):

On Start div click you need to update your other Div to show the updated value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>

            <script>
                var scr1 = 0;
    var scr2 = 0;
    var counter = 0;

    window.onload = function () {
    var YS = document.getElementById("YS");
    var CS = document.getElementById("CS");
    var mid = document.getElementById("mid");

    YS.innerHTML = "Your Score :  " + scr1 + counter  ;
    CS.innerHTML = "Com Score  :  " + scr2 ;

     }


    function srt() {
         counter++;
      mid.innerHTML = counter;
      YS.innerHTML = "Your Score :  " + scr1 + counter  ;
      CS.innerHTML = "Com Score  :  " + scr2 ;
    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2 class="scr1" id="YS">Your Score :</h1>
        <h2 class="scr2" id="CS">Com Score :</h2>
        <br />
        <br />
        <center>
        <div class="mid" id="mid"><p>0</p></p></div>
        <div class="srt" id="none" onclick="srt()">
            <h4>Start</h4>
        </div>
        </center>

        </body>
    </html>
```